# Searching on Connected Server Volumes aka "Shared"

Tags: javascript, macos, shell, applescript

It is always possible to use simple `find` pointing into a folder on the desired volume we want to perform the search. But what if I have e.g. 10+ **volumes** attached, **how would I quickly Search through all of them** simultaneously?

At the moment I simply create variable for each volume, and search each volume seperatly until it finds what I am looking for.

If I search manually, it can be quickly accomplished by selecting "Shared" in Finder. Is there anything equivalent in Shell/Apple Script/JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: Finder uses Spotlight, so you might take a look at [mdfind](https://ss64.com/osx/mdfind.html).

Comment: `mdfind` is great, but if any volumes were Ejected it needs constant reindexing with `mdutil` . Which is counterproductive

Comment: Spotlight keeps a data store on each volume (unless it is in the privacy list), but that is essentially what your manual Finder search is using.